# How to generalize the principle of mathematical induction for proving statements about more than one natural number?

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

Suppose that $P(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_N)$ be a proposition function involving $N >1$ positive integral variables $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_N$. Then how to generalise the familiar induction to prove this statement?

Can the following possibly be correct?

(1) Suppose that $P(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ is true.

(2) Suppose the truth of $P(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_N)$ implies the truth of $P(k_1+1, k_2+1, \ldots, K_N+1)$.

Then $P(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_N)$ is true for all $(n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_N) \in \mathbb{N}^N$.

For example, can we generalise induction to prove the following statement?

> Let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers such that $m < n$, and let $x$ be a real number such that $0 < x \leq \frac 1 2$. Then $$n^x - m^x < (n-m)x.$$

Comment: The proposed principle is not correct. The induction step would require (say for $2$ variable for brevity) that $P(x,y)$ implies $P(x+1,y)$ **and** $P(x,y+1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas (using double induction) how to prove the truth or otherwise of the proposition at the very end of my post?

Comment: Does it have to be double induction? Or induction at all? If any proof will do, then perhaps when I have the time I can write one out.

Comment: @AndréNicolas any proof will do, but the one by induction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

While this can indeed be done, your described approach certainly isn't enough - here's a counterexample! Let $P(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ be the statement $$"x_1=x_2=...=x_n."$$ Then $P(1, . . . , 1)$ is true, and $P(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ implies $P(x_1+1, . . . , x_n+1)$, but clearly $P$ is not true in general.

What's going on is that this scheme fails to take into account the fact that we need to allow the variables to increment *independently*. Based on this, can you see what type of statement you'll need to prove in general?

---

If you get stuck, you might also google the phrase "double induction" and see if you can generalize that to $n$-many parameters. But I suggest trying to figure it out yourself, first.

Comment: and what about the truth of the very last proposition? How to prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 2):

The question about generalized induction has been dealt with in the answer by Noah Schweber. Here is a quick non-induction proof of the desired inequality. Note that it works under conditions substantially more general than the conditions in the OP.

For fixed exponent $x$, consider the function $f(t)=t^x$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem we have
$$\frac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m}=f'(c)$$ for some $c$ between $m$ and $n$.

Note that $f'(t)=xt^{x-1}$, so $f'(c)=xc^{x-1}$. But since $x-1$ is negative and $c\gt 1$, we have $c^{x-1}\lt 1$, and therefore $xc^{x-1}\lt x$. This completes the proof.